# Как должно выглядеть условие, если перед ним расположена функция?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом нужно изменить скрипт, чтобы можно было работать с условием "если то" для следующей функции:

**-- Jquery --**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.photo li').waitForImages(function() { // Функция, которая следит, загрузилась ли картинка.
    if($(this)){
      $(this).show(); // если картинка найдена, показываем элемент с картинкой.
    }else{
      $(this).remove(); // если нет, удаляем элемент.
    }
  });
});
```

**-- CSS --**

```css
.photo:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1) {background: url("../img/cake.jpg") no-repeat;} - такая картинка есть.
.photo:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1) {background: url("../img/caked.jpg") no-repeat;} - такой нет.
.photo:nth-child(3) li:nth-child(1) {background: url("../img/cakef.jpg") no-repeat;} - такой нет.
.photo li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 270px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

**-- HTML --**

```html
<ul class="photo">
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class="photo">
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class="photo">
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: если что "то"? формулируйте пожалуйста понятнее

Comment: waitForImages() это из какой библиотеки?

Answer (score 1):

Решение может быть подобным этому:
Работающий пример http://jsbin.com/kikedeqeki/edit?html,output

```
$(function(){
    $('.photo > li').each(function(i, el) {
        var bgImg = new Image();
        bgImg.src = getComputedStyle($(this).get(0)).backgroundImage.split('"')[1];
        bgImg.onerror = function(){
             $(el).remove();
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).get(0)===this`

Comment: @Grundy да уже привык к этим $(this), $(this), $(this)... да и вообще el можно было.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/95gz9sav/

```
$(function(){
    $('.photo li').waitForImages({
        each: function(loaded, count, success) {
            $(this)[success ? 'show' : 'remove']();
        },
        waitForAll: true
    });
});
```